# ListView with many pictures thumbnails

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory

I have a ListView with many lines (about 200).

In each item of the ListView there is a thumbnail picture.

The pictures are downloaded for form the internet as the ListView scrolls.

The problem is that if I scroll rapidly the ListView it gets sluggish and quickly I get an Out of Memory error.

Please could you suggest an approach on how to avoid this?

Comment: do you use any image loader for images ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMRnGDR6Cu0&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_XOgcRukSoKKjewFJZrKV0&index=52. Lazy load images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [View Holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) pattern on the custom adapter you're using with lazy loading.

[Lazy Loading](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) using Universal Image Loader.

OR

you could give [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) / [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) Libraries a shot. They can handle caching efficiently for you.

Comment: Picasso is realy simple and works well... I recommend you to try it

Answer (score 1):

The basic flow is to use a caching system:
Download Image to your cache directory -> read it back into memory cache -> scale it down (if the image is larger than the the image view that displays it) -> display it in your image view.

The official android training has a great [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) along with full source code on how to create something like this.
They address the common issue of scrolling lag by pausing the background task(s) while user is scrolling.

Out Of memory is addressed through [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html).

Alternatively you can use a third party library like the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for addressing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You must handle your view recycling. It's a very important performance issue and you should always handle it.

See [this post](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/03/12/recycling-views-listview), it will guide you in this process, handling the view recycling and using the **View Holder** pattern. Also [see this](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/).

There are many reasons for recycling views:

- Object creation is relatively expensive. Every additional object that is created needs to be dealt with by the garbage collection system, and at least temporarily increases your memory footprint;
- This is more important for more complex views, but inflating and laying out the view objects can be expensive. Most often, you are only making minor changes to the view in getView that won't affect the layout (e.g, setting text) so you might be able to avoid the layout overhead;
- Remember that android is designed to be run in a resource constrained environment;
  Finally, its already done for you, and it certainly doesn't hurt anything, so why not use it;

Hoe it helps you.